# Preloading Images JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, preload

I am trying to preload images using Javascript. I am to suppose to use onload function and modularized coding. I have the codes below, but it does not seem to work. Any suggestions would greatly be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```js
function preloadImages() {
    if (document.images) {
        var img1 = new Image();
        var img2 = new Image();
        var img3 = new Image();

        img1.src = "images/banner1.jpg";
        img2.src = "images/banner2.jpg";
        img3.src = "images/banner3.jpg";
    }
}
function addLoadEvent(func) {
    var loadImages = window.onload;
    if (typeof window.onload != "function") {
        window.onload = func;
    } else {
        window.onload = function() {
            if (loadImages) {
                loadImages();
            }
            func();
        };
    }
}
addLoadEvent(preloadImages);
```

Comment: **First:** You shouldn't overwrite the global windows onload function. Instead, you can use `window.addEventListener` like so:
`window.addEventListener('load', preloadImages);`
**Second:** The path to your image may not be correct. How are you serving your html/javascript? Is it from the same domain as your images are hosted from?

Comment: "does not seem to work"? Well, that won't put those images on your screen, but they're in your cache.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I have figured it out based on your answers combined.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what you're trying to do. Perhaps this can help?

```js
function ImgMaker(basePath){
  this.img = function(url, doneFunc, errorFunc){
    var img = new Image();
    var b = basePath ? basePath.replace(/(\\|\/)$/) : '';
    if(doneFunc)img.onload = doneFunc;
    if(errorFunc)img.onerror = errorFunc;
    img.src = b+url;
    return img;
  }
}
var doc, bod, im = new ImgMaker;
function noError(){
  console.log(this.src+' loaded');
}
function error(){
  console.log(this.src+" did't load");
}
addEventListener('load', function(){
doc = document; bod = doc.body;
bod.appendChild(im.img('img1.png', noError, error));
bod.appendChild(im.img('img2.png', noError, error));
bod.appendChild(im.img('img3.png', noError, error));
bod.appendChild(im.img('img4.png', noError, error));
bod.appendChild(im.img('img5.png', function(){
  console.log(this.src+' loaded'); // showing anonymous way
  // want async? load another image here
}, function(){
  console.log(this.src+" didn't load");
}));
}); // end load
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this.